# Bind MySQL variables when using INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a simple SQL insertion into a two field MySQL table (records):

Where 'id' is the primary key (int) ... and 'photo' is a mediumblob

```
$photo = <binaryfile>
$id    = recordNo

  $MYSQL = "INSERT INTO records (id, photo) 
                 VALUES (?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE photo = ?";

$cursor->execute( *what goes in here? I have 3 ?'s but only 2 variables* );
```

Comment: It would help to know the language… PHP? Perl?

Comment: That code does not compile. Is `binaryfile` a file handle that you are reading from? Is `recordNo` a function?

Comment: Yes, you're right - it's just trimmed down pseudo code to explain the underlying problem ... the important parts for the question are the mysql and variable binding

Comment: On a tangent to your original question, you can use the `VALUES` keyword in MySQL to get rid of that third bind parameter. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE photo = VALUES(photo)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the execute function you should pass the array like this:

```
$cursor->execute(array($id,$photo,$photo));
```

Here `$photo` name should come two time one is for second one and next is for third `?` mark.

Comment: I had already tried that ... as soon as it tries to do the first 'insert' it fails with "execute failed: called with 3 bind variables when 2 are needed"

Comment: Apologies, you were right first time when you said "three" ... I missed a comma out in my haste to test your answer :)